# difference between vuejs local registration syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, components

I found out there is two ways to make local registration in vuejs:

**1) assigning components to a variable:**

`const components = { 'test-selector': TestSelector, };`

**2) declaring it as an object**

`components:{ 'test-selector': TestSelector, };`

what is the difference between these 2 syntax ?

find illustrative example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: my-app,
data: function(){
return {
count:0
}
},
components:{
'test-selector': TestSelector
}

})
```

---

```
const components = {
'test-selector': TestSelector
};

for (const key in components) {
  Vue.component(key, components[key]);
}
```

Comment: The question lacks the context. "assigning components to a variable" - where did you see that? Assigning to a variable does nothing on its own.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've edited question by adding an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet uses locally registered components, i.e. the ones that are used in `my-app` DOM template. This doesn't affect nested `test-selector` components, in case there are any.

The second snippet uses globally registered components and affects all `test-selector` components used in `Vue` instance.

Comment: I kinda didn't get you well, how global/local registration do affect or not all test-selector components ? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: As said, local registration doesn't affect nested test-selector components. Components within other components. Global registration affects all test-selector components, that's why it's called global

Comment: that's ok, I've understood that locally registered components don't get affected wheras the globally registered ones gets affected I just didn't get what it is even meant by **affect** in theses cases, could you give an example ?

Comment: in the other hand, can you tell me if `Vue.component({})` is equivalent to `const vm = new Vue({}); vm.component` ?

Comment: No, `Vue` is Vue application instance (the only one in v2, the one you create with createApp() in v3). And `vm` is root component instance, the same as `this` inside a component. You don't have `this.component`, unless you defined it yourself

Comment: I based it on this: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration#global-registration `const app = createApp({})

app.component()`

Comment: That's correct, this is app instance, and root comp instance would be `vm = app.mount(el)`, it wouldn't have component()